# How to use plist on Visual studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm currently developing an android apps using visual studio 2017. I'm still new to this. Basically, my application is sort of a questionnaire that requires the user to answer, and it will produce result.

So this is the layout that user requires to tick. I got a few problem here, Firstly, I didn't know how to make the radio button work. I want the user to click the radio button and from each click, it will compare with the data and after filling all the data user is required to click submit and it will produce the result. I use plist to store the data because I want my apps to be able to work offline.

[image]

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649839/android-parse-plist-file

Comment: And refer to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/.